# Runtime Stack for .NET Core 3.0 in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to setup a WebAp on Azure for asp.net core 3.0

However, the drop down box for "runtime stack" only allows .net core 2.2 as maximum.

Is .net core 3.0 not supported in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/#ASP.NET%20Core%20Module

### .NET Core on App Services

**Partially Current**

*The runtime and shared frameworks are there, but the .NET SDK is missing. You can run 3.0, but not build 3.0.*

Seems like you need to build your app as self-contained then deploy? You can check which regions support what in greater detail, using the map.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. Indeed, for Publish, I have the options "Code" and "Docker Container". For "Code", I can select version 2.2 as a maximum. For "Docker Container", it seems I need to create a self-contained app.